# Activity top-left corner back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I've a simple question; I noticed that some activities have in their top-left corner a back button (for example in contacts details)
Is it possible to display it in any kind on activities? If yes, How?

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html check this

Comment: Be sure to mark the correct answer as accepted. Failing to do so could make people avoid answering your future questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is referred to as "up" navigation (despite the fact that it points left...). You can enable it by [calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` on the `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function getSupportActionBar()

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    ...
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

[references](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-and-customize-back-button-of-action-bar-in-android/)